# Monitoring all the information of users using mvc 4 web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-web-api

I have a REST service based on mvc 4 and web api. I need to monitor all the users who are using my service (eg: user name , organization that user belongs to, how many hours he  is accessing service and so). can you please provide best architecture for this. what is the best way to doing this?

Comment: i recommend you putting a global log filter where you can log the user and credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom HttpMessageHandler for doing authentication and track all the information you need about the user in a database.  You will need some background processing of that data and doing some statistics about the usage of the API. About the message handler, a good start is the one provided in Thinktecture.IdentityModel library (You can customize it), 
http://leastprivilege.com/2013/04/22/asp-net-web-api-security-the-thinktecture-identitymodel-authenticationhandler/